# dataBound hitting twice when I search in kendo dropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm fairly new to kendo and facing a problem with kendo dropDownList.

I have Channel list kendo dropDown in my Add/Edit popup form. And every time I save my form and click on new Add/Edit I want that saved channel name in that dropDownList.
I'm calling the dropDown data from a SP and then populating that DropDown.

Here is my kendo DropDown:

```
function buildChannelDropDown(){
$('#ddlChannelSelect').kendoDropDownList({
  dataTextField: 'Text',
  dataValueField: 'Value',
  optionLabel: "Select Main Station",
  dataBound: function(e){
    if(!onDataBound_SelectByDefaultIfOnlyOneItem(e)) {
      var dropdownlist = $("#ddlChannelSelect").data("kendoDropDownList");
      var mainChannelDataSource = dropdownlist.dataSource;

      if(mainChannelDataSource._data.length > 0){
        dropdownlist.select(0);
      }
    }
  },
  change: function(){
    var selectedChannel = 0;
    if($('#ddlChannelSelect').val() != ""){
      selectedChannel = $('#ddlChannelSelect').val()
    }
    GetDataForSelectedChannel(selectedChannel);
  },
  filter: 'contains'
});
```

}

And this my function which brings all channel list from backend

```
  function setChannelDropDown(){
var paramObj = {
  ChannelGroupId = $("#ddlChannelGroup").val();
}
InvokeAjaxMethod('/Channel/GetChannelList', 'Get', true, paramObj, function(response){
  var channelDropDown = $('#ddlChannelSelect').data('kendoDropDownList');
  channelDropDown.setDataSource(response.Data);
});}
```

i'm calling setChannelDropDown() function on Add/Edit button click. Everything is working fine and newly added Channel gets shown in dropDown. Except when I search/type in Filter box in Dropdown(I have kept fiter: "contains"). When I search and select an option and save the form, Popup Form gets close but DropDown opens up. See this Image.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYBW0.jpg)

This DropDown opens up on grid after saving and closing form. After Debugging it came to known that dataBound gets hit again. This happens only when I type in filter box and save.
Does anyone know I can solve this and prevent it from happening?

Comment: Can you show how the grid is configured, or replicate the issue in a [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/) ?

Comment: You can have more control by binding a handler to only fire once with [one](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/observable/methods/one) .